# C++ Copy constructor for a pointer to vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a class `A`, which has as a member a pointer to a vector of pointers (`current`), the vector which contains a pair of an integer and an object of class `B` . I need to be able to create copies for objects of class `A`, and for that I use a `Clone` function (see code below). However, when I use this function, the pointers seem to be pointing to the same memory location, instead of different ones. I think the solution to this is to implement a copy constructor for my class in order to be able to properly copy my objects, but I am failing to do so.

Here is how my class looks like and the several tries I had for implementing the copy constructor:

```
class A {
public:
    A();
    A(const A &a);
    ~A();
    A* Clone() {return new A(*this);}
    std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, B*>> *current;
};
```

EDIT: The constructor and destructor are implemented as follows:

```
A::A() {
    current = new vector<std::pair<unsigned int, B*>>;
}

A::~A() {
    std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, B*>>::iterator cit = current->begin(), cend = current->end();
    for (; cit != cend; ++cit) {
        delete cit->second;
    }
    delete current;
}
```

Option #1:

```
A::A(const A &a){
    *current = *a.current;
}
```

Option #2:

```
A::A(const A &a){
    for(int i = 0; i < current->size(); i++) {
        (*current)[i] = (*a.current)[i];
    }
}
```

Option #3:

```
A::A(const A &a){
    for(int i = 0; i < current->size(); i++) {
        (*current)[i].first = (*a.current)[i].first;
        (*current)[i].second = new B((*a.current)[i].second);
    }
}
```

Options #1 and #2 give me segmentation fault, while for #3 I get the error: `no match for operator *`

Which is the correct way to implement the copy constructor and also should my `Clone` function be implemented differently?

Comment: Is there a reason for holding vector by pointer? Mostly pointer is redundant. Also, `new A(*this);` will just copy the pointer. +1 reason for dropping the pointer.

Comment: Why are you using pointers here at all?

Comment: This is the code base I have to work with so I cannot make that many changes. Class `A` was already defined like I explained in my question, I just need to copy objects of its type, so I added the `Clone` function, but that does not do what I want, hence I also need the copy constructor

Comment: did you mean `~A();` for the second `A();`?

Comment: Yes. I edited the question. Thank you

Comment: How can it be the case base when you need to edit the code in the question?  If it was from the code base it  would be a cit and paste job

Comment: The code base contained everything but the `Clone` function and the copy constructor and I need to add those because I want to be able to copy objects of class `A`

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor does not initialise the `current` member at all.   In any of the options.

From there, accessing its value (i.e. the value of the pointer named `current`) gives undefined behaviour.   And so does dereferencing it.  The usages of `*current` or `*a.current` in all options (and variations therefore) therefore ALL give undefined behaviour.

If you insist that the member `current` must be a pointer, it must be initialised in ALL constructors.   For example, the constructor `A::A()` (which you haven't shown) must look something like

```
 A::A() : current(new std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, B*>>(0))
 {
     //   initialised current with no elements
     // add pairs to the vector

     current->push_back(std::make_pair(0U, new B));
     current->push_back(std::make_pair(42U, new B));
 }
```

and the copy constructor must start with something akin to

```
A::A(const A &a) : current (new std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, B *>>(a.current->size())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < current->size(); i++)
    {
        (*current)[i].first = (*(a.current))[i].first;
        (*current)[i].second = new B((*(a.current))[i].second);
    }
}
```

More generally, however, there is actually no reason for `current` to be a pointer created using operator `new`.   In that case the constructors could be simplified to

```
 A::A() : current(0)
 {
     // add pairs to the vector

     current.push_back(std::make_pair(0U, new B));
     current.push_back(std::make_pair(42U, new B));
 }
```

and the copy constructor to

```
A::A(const A &a) : current (a.current.size())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < current.size(); i++)
    {
        current[i].first = a.current[i].first;
        current[i].second = new B(a.current[i].second);
    }
}
```

You've also provided no compelling information to suggest that `current` needs to be `vector<pair<unsigned, B *>>` rather than `vector<pair<unsigned, B>>`.   If the vector doesn't need to hold pointers (i.e. it holds objects directly) then, practically, you will not need to define the copy constructor at all - the compiler-generated default will suffice.    And your code will not need to use operator `new` at all (except, possibly, in `A::Clone()`).

Note that, if you do actually need to hand-roll a copy constructor, you will probably need to also hand-roll an `operator=()` and a destructor.   Look up "rule of three" (before C++11) or (C++11 and later) "rule of five" and "rule of zero" for more information.

Comment: I do have the constructor and destructor implemented. I edited the question such that the code for them is included. As for why I use pointers everywhere, and not just values, again this is the code I have to work with and I cannot change that much, I am just trying to use what I already have. If I use the copy constructor as you defined it, I get the error: `no match for operator * (operand type is 'std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, B*> >')`

Comment: I've fixed a minor typo.   However, if you're getting that error message, there is something in your code you haven't shown.   The first version of the copy constructor (with `current` a pointer) used exactly the same code as your option 3, except for initialising `current` so it actually points to an object and initial brackets to allow for operator precedence.    The second version I gave is for `current` not being a pointer.

Comment: At what other parts of the code I should look to be able to fix this error? I thought there were no more relevant parts I should include from the code

Comment: The error suggest that you're trying to use * on an already dereferenced `current` member. Just post the function where the error occurs.

Comment: The error occurs in the copy constructor. I implemented it as suggested in the answer